# SBT vs Maven for a new Scala/Spark project?

Tags: maven, sbt

Am new to Scala/SBT but have experience in Java/Maven.
For a new Scala/Spark project, what should be the choice: SBT or Maven?

PS- I intend to use Eclipse or IntellijIdea as IDE.

Thanks

ATT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also been looking into this question. Here are some things I have found.

According to the Apache Spark documentation:

> Maven is the official build tool recommended for packaging Spark, and is the build of reference. But SBT is supported for day-to-day development since it can provide much faster iterative compilation. More advanced developers may wish to use SBT. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-sbt

Three reasons I have heard for SBT:

1. It was built for Scala
2. It has incremental compilation
3. .sbt files tend to be more compact

In response though

1. Maven works just as well
2. If you are using the [JetBrains IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) IDE, which has a free edition, it has its own incremental compilation.

I think I will decide to go with Maven as it integrates better with my build server (continuous deployment).

Comment: "Maven is the official build tool recommended for packaging Spark" comment is about building Spark (the framework itself). That is not about Spark applications.